# Can't set the state on updating an object's property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a handler which is meant to update the 'quantity' property of my 'selected' array state. I have multiple fields for different items of which the quantities have to be updated by the user.When I am trying to update the state though, I get that maximum depth has been reached. When I use console.log, I get over 1000 calls of the handler somehow.. Maybe someone could guide me in what I am doing wrong. Here is the code:

```js
{
  this.state.purchase.selected.map(item => {
    return (
       <Grid item xs={4}>
          <OrderItemsCard
             item={item}
               onChange={this.handleSelectedItemChange(item)} />
       </Grid>
             )
          })
        }
```

```html
this.state = {
            purchase: {
                selected: [],
                comments: ''
            },
        }
   this.state.purchase.selected = []
        for (let i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j <= items.length - 1; j++) {
                if (this.props.data[i] === this.props.items[j]._id) {
                    this.state.purchase.selected.push(this.props.items[j])
                }
            }
        }

 handleSelectedItemChange = (item) => {
        let selected = Object.assign([], this.state.purchase.selected)
        selected.forEach(selectedItem => {
                selectedItem.quantity = item.quantity
        })
        this.setState({selected})
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 onChange={this.handleSelectedItemChange(item)}
```

which directly calls the handler and passes its result as the event handler, you want to pass a function instead:

```
 onChange={() => this.handleSelectedItemChange(item)}
```

---

And instead of shallow copying:

```
  let selected = Object.assign([], this.state.purchase.selected)
```

you want to deep copy there:

```
 let selected = this.state.purchase.selected.map(selected => {...selected});
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the error.. but my value still won't get saved.. Sorry, I am pretty new at this.

Comment: @someguy please provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: Apparently, the second item will get the value of the first one somehow.

Comment: why using the spread operator when selected is the state ? It is not working for me